# Identify which UISwitch is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I have multiple UISwitches on settings view, and linked all UISwitches to same IBAction function.

```
 @IBAction func settingSwitchTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

 }
```

How do i find which UISwitch is tapped so that i just save only the switch that actually changed (instead of saving all others also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the sole purpose of the `sender` parameter.

If all your switches are defined as IBOutlets, you can compare `sender` to each of them in order to know which one you've tapped.

You can also give each of them a different `tag` property, and decide what to do based on `sender.tag`.

Comment: Great!  For comparision we have to change the sender:AnyObject to sender: UISwitch

Answer (score 0):

Set tag for each Switch with a unique no.

you can get exact switch by using following :

```
switch = sender.tag
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func settingSwitchTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    switch (sender.tag){
    case 101: // your tag
        // executable code goes here
    break;
    case 102: // your tag

        break;
    case 103: // your tag

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```